# How do I fix the thumb to make it move better?

Tags: mesh, rigging, bones, transforms

[image]Ok I got to ask. How do CGI animators make the thumbs on their character models move so fluently, and look good, the fingers are ok but the thumb is more tricky. Sometimes it's to long, and it doesn't have a knuckle bulge, or a plump under the hand I just want it to look like a human thumb, how do I do that?[image]

file: https://pasteall.org/blend/559c31a48022402cade0f040ddaee231

Comment: Hello, maybe share this part of your object + armature so that we can give a try? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Did you get it?

Comment: Alright i think it worked now did you get it?

Comment: sorry, here you go https://pasteall.org/blend/559c31a48022402cade0f040ddaee231

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you are almost good, see what I can do with your current topology and armature:

[image]

It's this part that is probably not round enough, maybe you need to add topology and create a shapekey for when the fist is clenched?

[image]

Note that you could give a *Copy Rotation* constraint to your fingers so that you can clench the fist more easily.